# Finding index of row from a list

Tags: list, scala, search, scala-collections

I am trying to get the index of a row using Scala from a list consisting of lists of integers `List[List[Int]]`. I already have two functions that given the row index/column index and the grid as parameters, it outputs all the elements in that row. What I need is a function that given a particular element (eg: `0`), it finds its row index and column index and puts them in a list: `List[(Int, Int)]`. I tried to code a function that gives back an index when encountering 0 and then I passed the function to the whole grid. I don't know if I'm doing it the right way. Also, I couldn't figure out how to return the list.

**Also, I cannot use any loops.**

Thanks in advance.

```
 def Possibilities(): List[Int] =  {

     def getRowIndex(elem: Int): Int = elem match
   {
     case 0 => sudoku.grid.indexOf(sudoku.row(elem))
     case x => x
    } 

 val result1 = sudoku.grid map {row => row map getRowIndex}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think with two dimensions it is much easier to write such a method with `for` comprehensions.

Given a `List[List[Int]]` like this:

```
val grid = List(
     List(1, 2, 3),
     List(4, 5, 6),
     List(3, 2, 1))
```

we can simply walk through all the rows and columns, and check whether each element is the one we are looking for:

```
def possibilities(findElem: Int): List[(Int, Int)] = {
  for (
    (row, rowIndex) <- grid.zipWithIndex;
    (elem, colIndex) <- row.zipWithIndex
    if elem == findElem
  ) yield (rowIndex, colIndex)
}
```

The `yield` keyword creates a collection of the results of the `for` loop. You can find more details on Scala's `for`loop syntax [here](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/builtin-control-structures.html#sec%3afor-expressions) (and a more thorough discussion on how this relates to `map`, `flatMap`, etc. [here](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/for-expressions-revisited.html)).

So, if you don't want to use a `for` loop, simply 'translate' it into an equivalent expression using `map`. `flatMap`, and `withFilter`:

```
def possibilities(findElem: Int): List[(Int, Int)] = {
  grid.zipWithIndex flatMap { rowAndIndex =>
    rowAndIndex._1.zipWithIndex.withFilter(_._1 == findElem) map { colAndIndex =>
      (rowAndIndex._2, colAndIndex._2)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I am restricted from using any loops

Comment: Ah, sorry --- wasn't aware of that. No problem, `for` comprehensions can be mapped to combinations of `map`, `flatMap`, etc. (see http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/for-expressions-revisited.html).

Comment: Is it possible to explain what this line is doing please: grid.zipWithIndex

Comment: `zipWithIndex` is defined by list (see here: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List); it converts a list (like `List("Alice", "Bob")`) into a list where each element contains a tuple of the original element and its index (e.g. for the above example: `List(("Alice",0), ("Bob", 1))`). Just use the Scala REPL and play around with it! :-)

Comment: Not all of your approach is wrong (e.g. you figured out that you should use `map`), but some aspects are (e.g. the signature of `possibilities` should return a `List[(Int,Int)]`), and in other ways your solution is just incomplete (e.g. the indices need to be returned). I would recommend you just play around with the code, in the REPL, and read up on all important topics to solve the task (e.g. `for` expressions, tuples, `List`).

Answer (score 0):

Step 1, create a collection of all possible tuples of indices, with a `for` comprehension (`for` looks like a loop but it is not)

```
val tuples = for (i <- grid.indices; j <- grid.head.indices) yield (i, j)
```

Step 2, filter this collection

```
tuples.filter { case (i, j) => grid(i)(j) == valueToFind }
```